# In Docusaurus, is there can I preserve capitalization in anchors created from headings in docs?

Tags: docusaurus

I'm using Docusaurus to publish documentation for an open source library's API. The headings of my source markdown files correspond to the names of methods and properties for classes in the library. This all works fine.

However, the anchors that are created in the HTML are all lowercase. I want them to respect the capitalization used in the markdown file.

For example, this markdown header:

```
###.doSomething()
```

Generates the following HTML:

```
<h3>
    <a aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="..." id="dosomething"></a>. 
    <code>.doSomething()</code>
    <a class="..." href="#dosomething" title="...">#</a>
</h3>
```

As you can see, camelCase is transformed to lowercase. I would like to keep capitalization intact. Is it possible?

P.S. The markdown files are automatically generated from jsdoc comments. In jsdoc, links to a method or properties include capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can simply use explicit IDs to solve this issue: https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/headings#explicit-ids

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

1. Inside your project, navigate to the directory `node_modules > github-slugger`;
2. Open the `index.js` file;
3. **Remove** the line `if (!maintainCase) string = string.toLowerCase()`

The function will become something like this:

```
function slugger (string, maintainCase) {
  if (typeof string !== 'string') return ''
  // if (!maintainCase) string = string.toLowerCase() <-- remove this!

  return string.trim()
    .replace(specials, '')
    .replace(emoji(), '')
    .replace(whitespace, '-')
}
```

**IMPORTANT!**

1. If you `update` the `docusaurus`, you may need to apply this change again;
2. It may be necessary to edit the doc to see the changes, because of cache. Here I edited the `doc` file and it worked;
3. You must restart the `docusaurus` service after you make this change. And probably needs to clear the cache with `npm cache clear --force`;
4. Also, I think you should delete the folder `.docusaurus` to force the rebuild of all documents.

**RESULT**

[image: Result]

**The `.md` file:**

```
---
id: intro
---

# Random title

### WriNTinG with CaSeS

test 1

### .doAnotherThink()

test 3

### .doCamelCaseWithSeveralLETTERS()

test 3
```

---

**ROADMAP**

I must say that this one was hard. First I tried to track down the `anchor` tags, then the description. Eventually I found about the `github-slugger`, and looked like that was the way.

But once I made the changes, nothing had happened to the document! So after hours trying, I gave up… Then, just for curiosity, I decide to see what the `slug` function did to the document, by adding a second `header` with the same name. And — luck! — it kept the original case.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for looking into this. I just wish this was configurable. 

In fact, I just made a request for it (https://docusaurus.io/feature-requests/p/add-option-to-keep-capitalization-in-generated-heading-ids). It shouldn't be too hard since the slug() method already has an option for it...

Comment: I made the suggested change in the github-slugger code but it does not seem to be kicking in. I cleared the cache, removed the .docusaurus folder, and modified the .md file but it's still all lowercase.

Comment: I glad to (try) help! I just updated the answer with some "evidence" that it work, but it is something tricky… Try the following: go to `node_modules` and delete the folder `.cache`. Then, in your `.md` file, duplicate one header — just to force the `slug` function —, for example write `### .doSomething()` twice.

Comment: Also, do the above with the `docusaurus` service offline. And, just in case, double-check the slug function. (maybe the `docusaurus` changed it back?)

Comment: Thank you so much, once again, for your help. I don't know what I'm doing differently but it's still not working. I tried all your suggestions and the ID is still lowercase...

Comment: I am happy that you found a (way easier) solution! Sorry to rear about that did not worked out... But I saw that in future releases of the docusaurus will be a parameters to keep the *case* in the IDs.